# multidimensional arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a multidimensional object in JavaScript with the following structure:

```
arg: Array[2]
     2.0: "can_be_whatever"
     3.1: Array[6]
     1.0: Array[1]
          1.0: Object
                  1.    conc: false
                  2.    followers: Array[1]
                  3.    altVec: Array[0]
                  4.    parents: Array[0]
                  5.    regMsgs: Array[0]
                  6.    shared: Array[0]
                  7.    sharedWith: Array[0]
                  8.    consistsof: Array[3]
                                  1.    0: Array[1]
                                                  1.    0: "a"
                                                  2.    length: 1
                                                  3.    __proto__: Array[0]
                                  2.    1: Array[1]
                                                  1.    0: "a"
                                                  2.    length: 1
                                                  3.    __proto__: Array[0]
                                  3.    2: Array[1]
                                                  1.    0: "a"
                                                  2.    length: 1
                                                  3.    __proto__: Array[0]
                                  4.    length: 3
                                  5.    __proto__: Array[0]
                 9. unregMsgs: Array[0]
                10. part: 0
                11. __proto__: Object
```

I am quite new in JavaScript and i need to fetch the values "a" from the nested arrays. Can somebody propose something?

Comment: Please display the object as JSON instead

Comment: So you're using floats as indices?

Comment: This is not a javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this structure doesn't make any sense to me. I tried to "convert" it into a "real" JavaScript structure. I hope this gets close to what you meant:

```
var arg = [
    "can_be_whatever",
    [[{
        conc: false,
        followers: [null],
        altVec: [],
        parents: [],
        regMsgs: [],
        shared: [],
        sharedWith: [],
        consistsof: [["a"], ["a"], ["a"]],
        unregMsgs: []
    }], null, null, null, null, null]
];
```

You can then select the "a" values like so:

```
var consistsof = arg[1][0][0].consistsof;
for (var i = 0; i < consistsof.length; ++i) {
    console.log(consistsof[i][0]);
}
```

In JavaScript you can select values from an array using `[index]` (just like in any other programming language) and properties from an object using `.property` (like in Java).

Comment: Don't use "for in" statement for iteration over arrays - it's not safe (http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) and slower then 'for' statement with index incrementing.

Comment: Corrected it above, thanks for the tip. I already knew that `for in` isn't safe (what a shame, it looks way cooler xD), but I didn't know it's also slower...